# How can I deploy locally for different environments?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have to deploy locally to environments for development, test, and production so that also I have `.env`, `.env.development` and `.env.test`.

This is my package json

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
}
```

How can I deploy locally for different environments by reading `.env` or `.env.development` or `.env.test`?

so far i am typing this "yarn serve " for development

**EDIT 1:**

To deploy to test i did this:

```
"serve:": "vue-cli-service build --mode test"
```

But i did not created the enviroment file `.env.test` but its working, should not worked, firstly should read the corresponding file.

Comment: You don't need to have a .env file for staging to deploy for staging. 
When you deploy with a mode it will use the environment variables from that mode eg. .env.staging AND the general .env / .env.local.
You really should read the documentation I linked in my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--mode production`, `--mode development`, `--mode staging` etc. when building.

So the entire command would be `vue-cli-service build --mode production` (or any other environment instead of production)

Here is a link to the documentation about modes and environment variables :)
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html